# jQuery intercept slideToggle()

Tags: jquery

I'm doing a very simple slideToggle() here:

```
            $("#loginBtn").click(function(){
                $("#login").slideToggle();
                return false;
            });
```

What i'm asking is, how do i intercept the slideToggle, so once the user clicks #loginBtn and #login slides down, they can either click #loginBtn again to slide it up OR they can click another element to slide #login up? But only the #loginBtn slides down the #login?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind some `slideUp` goodness to your 'other elements'?

```
$(".otherButtons").click(function() {
    $("#login").slideUp();            
    return false;
});
```

Comment: yeah, i was probably over complicating things!